# The grid is missing and the button is grayed out

Tags: 3d-view

Thr grid floor is missing in the viewport and the button to activate/deactivate it is greyed out.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Im not sure, add the file so we can example. However, I know that the reason that the grid button is greyed out is because it only works in front, top and side orthographic modes ex. when you press numpad 1,3,7

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and is [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure overlay button is enabled.
[image: Overlay button might be disabled.]

Comment: you know what guys! thanks it was just a bug or something and yes overlay was turned on.. i launched blender just now and the grids are back idk why and sorry for writing in all caps i didnt mean shouting but sorry anyways thanks

Answer (score 1):

It may be turned off because you're view is set to "perspective" click on this icon so your view is "orthographic" and see if that fixes the problem[image]